# Multiply without + or *

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, racket

I'm working my way through [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org) on my own. I haven't quite grasped complex linear recursion, so I need a little help.

The problem:
Define `multiply`, which consumes two natural numbers, `n` and `x`, and produces `n * x` without using Scheme's `*`. Eliminate `+` from this definition, too.

Straightforward with the + sign:

```
(define (multiply n m)
  (cond
    [(zero? m) 0]
    [else (+ n (multiply n (sub1 m)))]))

(= (multiply 3 3) 9)
```

I know to use `add1`, but I can't it the recursion right.

Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, need to proofread my questions better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the problem in two functions. First, you need a function `(add m n)` which adds m to n. What is the base case? when n is zero, return m. What is the recursive step? add one to the result of calling `add` again, but decrementing n. You guessed it, `add1` and `sub1` will be useful.

The other function, `(mul m n)` is similar. What is the base case? if either m or n are zero, return 0. What is the recursive step? add (using the previously defined function) m to the result of calling `mul` again, but decrementing n. And that's it!

Comment: Thank. I was able to come up with a working method with your description.

Comment: and create the exponent function in the next exercise.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is almost certainly a homework-type question, hints only.

How do you add 7 and 2? While most people just come up with 9, is there a more basic way?

How about you increment the first number and decrement the second number until one of them reaches zero?

Then the other one is the answer. Let's try the sample:

```
7 2
8 1
9 0 <- bingo
```

This will work fine for natural numbers though you need to be careful if you ever want to apply it to negatives. You can get into the situation (such as with `10` and `-2`) where both numbers are moving away from zero. Of course, you could check for that before hand and swap the operations.

So now you know can write `+` in terms of an increment and decrement instruction. It's not fantastic for recursion but, since your multiply-by-recursive-add already suffers the same problem, it's probably acceptable.

Now you just have to find out how to increment and decrement in LISP without using `+`. I wonder whether there might be some specific instructions for this :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am really work through this book on my own time.

Comment: Sigh, this is just like c pointers all those years ago. I didn't get it, a week later still didn't get it, then all the sudden I get it. I know to use add1 and sub1, that part is clear.