# Multiplication using increments

Tags: java, recursion, increment

My assignment is to write a recursive function to multiply two numbers together, using only an addition function, `++`, and `--`. My addition function is:

```
public static int peanoplus(int x, int y) {
    if(y==0) return x;
    else return peanoplus(++x,--y);
}
```

What I have so far for my multiplication function is:

```
public static int peanotimes(int x, int y)
{
    if(y==0) return x;
    else return peanotimes(peanoplus(x,x),--y);
}
```

I am not exactly sure what to put in the first parameter for the `peanotimes` function. Right now the issue is that I'm doubling the number, rather than adding it to the original number. I know that I need to maintain the `x` variable so that the recursive calls can continue adding the original number (instead of doubling every time), but then where would I actually add the numbers?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270472/multiply-without-or) which is very similar to my question, but even with those tips I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( y == 0 || x == 0 ) { return 0; }
    else { return peanoplus(x, peanotimes(x,--y)); }
```

Comment: yes. you need to change `if(y==1) return x;` to `if(y==0 || x==0) return 0;` to work with all natural number. PS peano numbers not natural. natural numbers not include zero

Comment: Umm, yes they do - that's Peano axiom 1 !

Answer (score 1):

This version closest matches the formal Peano axiom of `x * S(y) = x + (x * y)`

```
public static int peanotimes(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0) {
        return 0;       // terminate recursion, NB: not "x"
    }  else {
        return peanoplus(x, peanotimes(x, --y));
    }
}
```