# How do I use mathematical operators like modulo in Brainfuck?

Tags: math, brainfuck

In BF, I know you can add and subtract with the `+` and `-` operators, and that you can multiply two pre-defined numbers like so:

```
Multiply 4 and 4
++++[>++++<-]
```

But how can I multiply two variables, or use other mathematical operators, such as modulo or division?

Comment: multiplication is just repeated addition; 4 * 4 == 4 + 4 + 4 + 4. similar for division/subtraction. exponentiation and modulo can also be expressed using addition and subtraction.

Comment: @PedrodelSol Could you leave an answer on how I would implement those?

Comment: [Multiplication using increments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907759/multiplication-using-increments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a generic looking routine to multiply two numbers in bf. Taken from [here](http://cydathria.com/bf/bf_ex3.html).

Multiply a value by another value
This requires multiple copies and nested loops.

```
Copy first operand to a work location
Move to work location and enter a loop
Move to second operand and copy to a work location
Move to second work location and enter a loop
Move to result location and increment
Move to second work location and decrement
Loop until second work location equals zero
Move to first work location and decrement
Loop until first work location equals zero
```

Example:

Multiply three (a[p]) times five (a[p+1]) and place the result in a[p+2].

```
+++>+++++< 
[>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<
[<<
  [>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<
  [<<+>>-]
<-]
```

Some further reading [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Divmod_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link:

https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms

it uses values such as temp0, x, y, etc. You should pick cells to hold these values, and replace the variable names with `>` or `<` to go to the cell holding it